# Maclaurin Series Complex Numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

I'm having trouble getting to the right solution on the function ${z^2\over (1+z)^2}$

${z^2\over (1+z)^2}$ = ${z^2}$${1\over (1+z)^2}$ = ${z^2}$${1\over (1+z)(1+z)}$ = ${z^2}$${A \over (1+z)}$ + ${z^2}$${B \over (1+z)}$ = ?

Beyond this point, I don't know how to get to the given solution:

$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \left(-1\right)^{\left(n+1\right)}nz^{\left(n+1\right)}$

Thanks in advance

Comment: pay attention to the fact that $(1+z)^2\ne(1+z)(1-z)$ or is it just a typo?

Comment: well no, it was really a mistake :/ maybe thats the problem with it. I'll check again, thanks

Comment: Now its even worse... how do I find A and B? or its not supposed to go this route?

I tried to go with (Z+1)^2 = 1+(z(z+2)) and make the sum but cant get too far

Comment: Think derivatives instead of partial fractions.

Comment: Well, you know that $1/(1+z^2)=1-z^2+z^4-z^6+z^8-\cdots$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** You can write this as $-z^2\cdot (\frac{1}{1+z})'$

Comment: Got it, thanks.